# Forcing bootstrap tab to be active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have several tabs and sub tabs underneath ***`#tab1`***.

```
<ul id="main-nav-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <li id="tab1"><a href="#tab1-tab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
    <li class="active" id="tab2"><a href="#tab2-tab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
    <li id="tab3"><a href="#tab3-tab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>

</ul>


<div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1-tab" class="tab-pane fade scrollable">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills"> 
            <li class="active"><a href="#first-subtab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#second-subtab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#third-subtab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
        </ul>
    <div id="subtab-container">
        <div id="subtab-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div id="first-subtab" class="tab-pane in active fade"></div>
            <div id="second-subtab" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
            <div id="third-subtab" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane in active fade">
    <table id="table2" class="table table-condensed"></table>
</div>          
<div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <table id="table3" class="table table-condensed"></table>
</div>
```

Right now, I have a couple sets of data, when you select one set, it loads all the tabs with data. When you select another set, it updates all the tabs with the new data.

When it loads, I have `#Tab2` as the main default active tab. When I click `#tab1`, I want `#first-subtab` to be the default active tab, but it always goes back to the last sub tab clicked from the last set of data.

*For example, I load data, it defaults to `#tab2`, and I click `#tab1` -> third-sub tab. When I load another set it defaults to `#tab2`, I click `#tab1`->* ***INSTEAD OF GOING TO `#first-subtab`, IT GOES TO `#third-subtab`*** *because I clicked it last.*

I've tried to set the `#first-subtab` to default with the following:

```
$('#tab1').click(function(){
    $('#third-tab').removeClass('li.active');
    $('#first-tab').addClass('li.active');             
});
```

I've also tried to show/hide accordingly, but nothing will force the `#first-subtab` to be default... Any suggestions?

My complete html is 197 lines. When I use the google developer tools, and I've clicked on `#first-subtab`, the one that I want to be active, it's under the following:

```
html -> body -> div.layout.layout-vertical -> div#views.visible
 -> div#table-container.fill -> div#tab-content.tab-content
 -> div#tab1.tab-pane.fade.scrollable.active.in -> ul.nav.nav-pills -> li.active -> a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Trevor's answer I was able to find the solution that worked for my code:

First, I had to add an id to my ul of my subtabs:

```
<ul id="subtabsID" class="nav nav-pills">
```

Then I used this to make the first-subtab the default subtab.

```
 $("#subtabsID > .active").removeClass('active');
 $("#subtabsID > :nth-child(1)").addClass('active');       
 $('#first-subtab').addClass('active in');
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the first sub tag active

Try:

```
 $('#tab1').click(function(){
            $('.nav-pills li').removeClass('active');
            $('.nav-pills li:first').addClass('active');             
        });
```

And use Guli's Suggestion to fix your tabs.

Look at Guli's fiddle for a merge of our two answers.

Comment: Yeah your right, I just up voted your answer.  But I think he is also looking to make the sub tags under tab1 always default to the first sub tab as active.

Comment: @Trevor, when I use that I get Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:first. I'm not sure what the colon notation means there.

Comment: I just saw your above comment, You are right, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user2847749 check this example: http://www.bootply.com/108839 It should work on most versions of jQuery.  Not sure why you are getting that error.  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_first.asp

Comment: @user2847749 maybe try `$('.nav-pills li').first().addClass('active');` using `.first()` instead of `:first` ...

Comment: I hard refreshed and the error went away, but both ways don't work for me. I can see the link you gave me and it working... don't know why it isn't working on my page. 
I did see this on your live example: `<div id="push"></div>`  was that doing anything? I dont know why it would work and mine isn't.

Comment: @user2847749 Maybe it's because your html is structured different.. Can you share your complete html in your question?

Comment: @Trevor, because my html is close to 200 lines, I updated the end of my question with information that might help you...thank you for your time!

Comment: @user2847749 you could try `$('#tab-content .nav-pills li').removeClass('active');`
            `$('#tab-content .nav-pills li:first').addClass('active');`  It will be hard to know without experimenting with or debugging the code.. But hopefully that works.

Comment: @trevor, it didn't work but I think you've pointed me in a different direction than I was going, so I'll keep trying this type of solution and hopefully I can figure this out. thank you

Comment: @Trevor, I found the solution and have added it, I can make it the solution tomorrow. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your a tag has a href value to #tab2-tab :

```
    <li class="active" id="tab3"><a href="#tab3-tab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
```

And you div has a bad ID value (not the same that the anchor) :

```
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
```

Fix the ID of div like this

```
        <div id="tab3-tab" class="tab-pane fade">
```

and it will work perfectly.

Same thing for #tab2.

If add the answer of @Trevor it will be perfect for your needs.

JSFiddle [Demo including Trevor point](http://jsfiddle.net/pbQqT/3/) !

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if you go to your jfiddle and click tab A -> A3 -> B -> A, then A3 is automatically default. I need A1 to be default in your example. i'd like a jquery example. I don't think it's my html, I had to make the names general for this question but I think html is fine in my code...